# Grid-like WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to implement a 'TabManager' control which can be instantiated much like a Grid in XAML. This looks like a fairly common task, but I couldn't seem to find a tutorial and I still don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I was wondering if anyone here had an example.

I'd want the XAML to generate the control to look something like this:

```
   <TabManager>
        <TabManager.TabDefinitions>
            <TabDefinition Caption="Tab 1"/>
            <TabDefinition Caption="Tab 2"/>
            <TabDefinition Caption="Tab 3"/>
        </TabManager.TabDefinitions>

        <TabPanel TabManager.Tab="0">
            <TextBlock Text="foo"/>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel TabManager.Tab="1">
            <TextBlock Text="bar"/>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel TabManager.Tab="2">
            <TextBlock Text="baz"/>
        </TabPanel>
    </TabManager>
```

The TabManager will render a few buttons and some elements to contain the TabPanels' children - e.g. place them into a DockPanel or whatever else I choose to do; shouldn't matter.

Comment: Are you looking to create User control ? [link] WPF User Control http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W

Comment: I'm more likely to derive from Panel, like Grid does. The main point of my question is how to support multiple children in the TabManager class.

Comment: So basically you want the TabManager to show the Tabs like a Grid layout?? But you only want the Horizontal line at the top so it looks like Tabs?? But the TabControl already has a similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `<TabControl>`?

For instance -

```
<TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab1" x:Name="Tab1">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="foo"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2" x:Name="Tab2">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="bar"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab3" x:Name="Tab3">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="baz"/>
            </Grid>
         </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```